Links to copyrighted material
I flagged these two questions because they contain links to complete copies of copyrighted work.

Pricing Principle 1
Arbitrage free implies complete market?

I could easily edit and remove the links, but I was hoping a moderator could remove them completely from the edit history and possible ask the user not to post links to copyrighted material again.
It's been a few days since I flagged the questions, and the links are still there. Should I simply edit the question and remove the links?

Note I'm referring to the links to the complete works, not the scanned images.

At first I assumed @Joshua Ulrich meant the scans which were fine by me. First response with that knowledge below:
I've handled these flags, marked them helpful and made a comment on them:

Discussed this*, it's up to the holder to contact SE and I don't want to set a precedent. Furthermore, this might constitute fair use. 

Note that we, the community moderators, can't be the final judge on this issue, we're neither qualified nor authorized. If the copyright holder wants this material removed he will have to file a DMCA request to the corporation behind SE.
Personally I don't see any ethical problems with this form of sharing the material: the source of the material is named and it can't be used instead of the original. Practically, I'd like to see a more condensed version of the same content (again sourced) so readers can digest and answer it more easily.
--
However, the user also linked to the complete book. This is discouraged. Please edit to remove and flag so moderators can take action against repeat offenders.
* In the moderator chat

I'm not a lawyer, but I don't see how posting two links to the entire book constitutes fair use, nor how those PDFs can't be used instead of the original. I suspect you're only considering the excerpts.

I see, that's bad. Thank you. Such blatant violations are not welcome. I will correct this immediately. However, I can not delete it completely, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114279/266114.

Thanks for that reference. Now I know to just edit and remove them myself, rather than bugging moderators.

Please also flag, so we can contact and warn repeat offenders.

Okay, I'll flag too. Thanks for all the work you've been doing over the past few weeks.
